# AngularJS $http.get not loading data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to load data from a json file but when I try to access through $http.get it just don't load, as if the file doesn't exists.

This is my controllers.js:

```
angular.module('QuizQuestions.controllers', [])
   .controller('Preguntas', function($scope,$http) {
      $http.get('data/preguntas.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.questions = data;
      });

      $scope.tags = [
        { text: 'just' },
        { text: 'some' },
        { text: 'cool' },
        { text: 'tags' }
      ];
 });
```

Then in the view when I try to access the "tags" data it works perfectly, but when I try with "questions", it's empty. If I explicity declare the $scope.questions instead of calling a file with $http.get it works.

Here my partial questions.html:

```
<h1>Questions</h1>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="question" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Question</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question" placeholder="Question">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="tags" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Tags</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <tags-input ng-model="tags">
        </tags-input>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <ul class="questions">
              <li ng-repeat="question in questions">
                <a href="#/questions/{{question.id}}">{{question.text}}</a>
              </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if I'm clear enough, please ask me if you don't understand anything.

Comment: Have you debugged it in your browser to see what the network call is returning?  Also, in a callback you are going to need to call `$scope.$apply();`

Comment: I've just watched, it returns a 500 Error, andI really don't understand why.

Comment: 500 error is on the server side, so it may not be an angular specific issue although some server side api's require specific headers/etc.  Not knowable via your question.  Does the file (`data/preguntas.json` exist in the path that is relative to the app ?

Comment: Try using [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) to debug your API endpoints before integrating them into your application.

Comment: Thank you both, I checked if something was wrong in the server and it's fixed now.

Comment: Never mind my answer, then.